# sharepoint webpart xlsx to list

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I have a problem. I create a webpart for sharepoint online in typescript. The user clik on button and choose the file manualy. the webpart select automaticaly the importante data in the xlsx data. But now I want push automaticaly data's in a sharepoint list but I can't find any answer on internet. If someone know how connect the webpart to the list can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem. You need to get the list name from the user, and the excel file you get from the user must be well-structured to store the contents of each cell in a special column in the list.
for example:

[image]